Convert Yolov4-tiny model weights to tflite
I have trained a YoloV4-tiny object detecion model using darknet by referring this tutorial. My images are of size 1024x64.
I got yolov4-tiny_custom_training_last.weights as output.
I want to convert this to tflite. I tried some methods but they are outdated or not supporting non-square images.
So how can I convert the yolov4-tiny darknet model weights to tflite?

Not an answer, but a comment:  do not use the ..._last.weights file.  Instead, you should be using the ..._best.weights file.  And if you don't have a ..._best.weights file, you didn't train correctly.  https://www.ccoderun.ca/programming/yolo_faq/#training_command

Thanks for the reply. I was using https://github.com/AlexeyAB/darknet.git where I wasn't getting any best.weights file. Now after referring the link you provided, I cloned the Hank.ai version of darknet and now I'm getting the best.weights file.
